# How to get logs of amazon sns by using aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I've added SNS application attributes for Message Delivery Status as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-msg-status.html

But I can't find any example of how to get log for sent notifications.

Answer (score 1):

SNS logs of message delivery status are sent to [Cloudwatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html).  You can see [examples of the SNS messages in cloudwatch logs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-msg-status.html#sns-msg-examples).

If you'd like to use the SDK to access the logs, the [Cloudwatch Logs API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) provides access, but the specific technique will depend on which SDK you're using, as the SDKs vary between different languages/technology platforms.

You probably want [GetLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html) or [FilterLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html) API calls, which are available in the SDKs, e.g.:

- [PHP GetLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-logs-2014-03-28.html#getlogevents)
- [Java GetLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/GetLogEventsRequest.html)
- [.NET GetLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html)

Links to the other SDKs are available from the Cloudwatch Logs API Page.